# How to read Excel file from memory stream?

Tags: c#, openxml, closedxml

I am trying to read an Excel file in a web api environment with ClosedXML. Since synchronous code is not allowed I am ready the body.request into a memory stream. But somehow I get an exception telling me the file data is corrupted when opening the Excel file. The exception root is somewhere in the constructor of System.IO.Packaging.ZipPackage.

> at System.IO.Packaging.ZipPackage..ctor(Stream s, FileMode packageFileMode, FileAccess packageFileAccess)
> at System.IO.Packaging.Package.Open(Stream stream, FileMode packageMode, FileAccess packageAccess)
> at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.PackageLoader.OpenCore(Stream stream, Boolean readWriteMode)
> at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.SpreadsheetDocument.Open(Stream stream, Boolean isEditable, OpenSettings openSettings)
> at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.LoadSheets(Stream stream)
> at Program.<$>d__0.MoveNext() in

So I thought that's a problem with the web api. I copied code to a console application. But same problem there. Why is this code not working?

```
using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(path, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
{
    using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var writer = new StreamWriter(memStream);
        writer.Write(await file.ReadToEndAsync());
        writer.Flush();
        memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook(memStream))
        {

        }
    }
}
```

But this code is working?

```
using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
{

    using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook(stream))
    {

    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

**edit: Added failing code below**

So this is my code which is not working:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.MapPost("/upload", (HttpRequest request) =>
{
    using(var workbook = new ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook(request.Body)) {
        return workbook.Worksheets.First().Name;
    }
})
.Accepts<IFormFile>("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");;

app.Run();
```

Throwing this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Synchronous operations are disallowed. Call ReadAsync or set AllowSynchronousIO to true instead.
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpRequestStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
> at System.IO.Stream.CopyTo(Stream destination, Int32 bufferSize)
> at System.IO.Stream.CopyTo(Stream destination)
> at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive..ctor(Stream stream, ZipArchiveMode mode, Boolean leaveOpen, Encoding entryNameEncoding)
> at System.IO.Packaging.ZipPackage..ctor(Stream s, FileMode packageFileMode, FileAccess packageFileAccess)
> at System.IO.Packaging.Package.Open(Stream stream, FileMode packageMode, FileAccess packageAccess)
> at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.PackageLoader.OpenCore(Stream stream, Boolean readWriteMode)
> at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.SpreadsheetDocument.Open(Stream stream, Boolean isEditable, OpenSettings openSettings)
> at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.SpreadsheetDocument.Open(Stream stream, Boolean isEditable)
> at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.LoadSheets(Stream stream)
> at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.Load(Stream stream)
> at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook..ctor(Stream stream, XLEventTracking eventTracking)
> at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook..ctor(Stream stream)

Ok I found a solution with the tip of @StefanFFM

Changed the code to this and now its working:

```
app.MapPost("/upload", async (HttpRequest request) =>
{
    using(var memStrem = new MemoryStream()) {
        await request.Body.CopyToAsync(memStrem);
        using(var workbook = new ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook(memStrem)) {
            return workbook.Worksheets.First().Name;
        }
    }
    
})
.Accepts<IFormFile>("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
```

Was kinda blind there and tried way to complex stuff.

Comment: That don't work. When I exchange writer.Flush() with FlushAsync() then I get "System.IO.FileFormatException: File contains corrupted data.".

Comment: await was there :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution. Working code (see in the first post for more details). CopyToAsync helped me out here.

```
app.MapPost("/upload", async (HttpRequest request) =>
{
    using(var memStrem = new MemoryStream()) {
        await request.Body.CopyToAsync(memStrem);
        using(var workbook = new ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook(memStrem)) {
            return workbook.Worksheets.First().Name;
        }
    }
    
})
.Accepts<IFormFile>("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
```

Answer (score 0):

StreamReader reads binary data and converts it into text using the specified encoding. That is not necessary for what you are trying to do. You just need to read binary data into a stream. One way to do it would be:

```
using (var memStream = new MemoryStream(await File.ReadAllBytesAsync(path)))
{ 
        memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook(memStream))
        {

        }
}
```

Comment: My problem is, that I dont have a file (I just tried to reproduce my problem in a console application). My "file" is coming from HttpRequest.Body here since its a web api call. I need a way to read that stream and pass it to XLWorkbook. And passing request.Body directly is not working :(

Comment: Please post your actual code then. I'm not sure why you can't just pass on the httpbody stream to the XLWorkbook constructor? Anyway you don't need a Reader/Writer, if anything you can just copy from one stream to to another (Stream.CopyTo).

Comment: Ok I added code, and while building a minimal example I somehow came to a solution with the help of your tip just to copy it to another stream....was trying to complex things there. Thank you anyway :)